# Meteor: how to open external links in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor, safari

I'm using Meteor 1.0.3.2 to make a hybrid app that contains links that access vendor websites.

My dilemma: I can't link out to Safari. All my links are loading in the WebView.

I've tried a couple methods that recommend editing my AppDelagate with code, but I'm more interested in an HTML fix and nothing I do seems to work.

I've been looking at deep linking but can't find much on Safari. The only working code I've found is using `href="x-web-search://?http://website.com"` to paste content into the Safari search bar. I figure that if I can do that, I should be able to target a website with some variation of the code. If anyone knows anything about this, please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking to do this as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37769326/how-to-use-correct-ios-link-schema-for-launching-external-apps-form-meteor-app

Answer (score 0):

You can allow it configuring your `mobile-config.js`with `App.accessRule` (see [meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html#App-accessRule). Type 'navigation' controls which URLs the WebView itself can be navigated to
(can also needed for iframes).

```js
App.accessRule('*://*.thevendorsite.com/*', { type: 'navigation' });
```